# OpenTK textures to display label text are showing up black

Tags: c#, opengl, textures, opentk

I am trying to make a basic plot viewer in C# using OpenTK. To show the title, x and y axis labels I am creating a bitmap of each from a text string and trying to use it as a texture at the specified position.

The string to bitmap works as I have saved these to disk and they appear as I want them. However somewhere between loading them into a texture and displaying them on the screen something is going wrong. All that is displayed are black rectangles. They look approximately the right size for the text I have entered, and they are in the right place, but I can't get them to display the correct texture.

[image: View of application]

The code for loading the bitmap into texture is here:

```
public static int LoadTexture(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Bitmap is null.");

        int id = GL.GenTexture();
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, id);

        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
        GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

        BitmapData bmpdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, bmpdata.Width, bmpdata.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bmpdata.Scan0);

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpdata);

        return id;
    }
```

And the one of the sections of code where I try to display it is here:

```
                GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
                GL.TexEnv(TextureEnvTarget.TextureEnv, TextureEnvParameter.TextureEnvMode, (float)TextureEnvMode.Modulate);

                #region Title
                {
                    Bitmap title = Graphics.Utilities.DrawText(_plot2D.Title, _font, _colorScheme.AxesLabels, _colorScheme.BackGround);
                    title.Save(@"S:\Projects\Visual Studio\SCG\Code\Graphics\Ogle\TestFiles\titleTest.png", ImageFormat.Png);

                    int titleID = SCG.Code.Graphics.Utilities.LoadTexture(title);
                    labelTextures.Add(titleID);

                    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, titleID);

                    double pl = w * _dim.PlotLeft;
                    double pr = w * _dim.PlotRight;
                    double pb = h * _dim.PlotBottom;
                    double pt = h * _dim.PlotTop;
                    double l = pl + (pr - pl - title.Width) / 2;
                    double r = pl + (pr - pl + title.Width) / 2;
                    double b = pt + (h - pt - title.Height) / 2;
                    double t = pt + (h - pt + title.Height) / 2;

                    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);

                    GL.TexCoord2(0, 1); GL.Vertex2(l, b);
                    GL.TexCoord2(1, 1); GL.Vertex2(r, b);
                    GL.TexCoord2(1, 0); GL.Vertex2(r, t);
                    GL.TexCoord2(0, 0); GL.Vertex2(l, t);

                    GL.End();
                }
                #endregion // title
```

I have looked up other answers and some people say it is to do with GL.Enable(TextureCap.Texture2D) but I have tried moving this around to different locations and even copying the command just before each attempt to display the texture but nothing changes the outcome.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Note that I have next to no experience in OpenTK, or OpenGL for that matter.

Comment: If you try to use a transparent texture, make sure you did set up the GL blend states correctly.

Comment: I just tried adding GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend) at the start and disable at the end of the OnPaint method and it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

I also tried changing all of the PixelFormats to RGB and that hasn't made a difference either.

Comment: just enabling it is not enought. You need to set appropriate blend functions/equations.

Comment: Well i'm intending these labels to be opaque. All of the colors used are standard Color.Black, Color.White etc so they don't have any transparency. Do you think it is not working because the PixelType is set to a color that could be transparent? That's why I said I tried changing all of the PixelFormat options to RGB instead of RGBA but that still didn't work.

Comment: Well, blending/transparency was just one of many possible explanations for the result you got. With using the RGB format, you prpbably ruled that out as the issue in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the fact that the currently loaded color was black. To apply textures the color had to be set to GL.Color3(Color.Transparent). Then the code worked fine.